# Вычисляемое свойство при v-model

Tags: vue.js

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newProduct.price_without_vat">
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newProduct.price_with_vat">
<script>
     newProduct : {} //это в data
</script>
```

Есть такой код.Инпуты заполняют объект,который потом я шлю на бэкенд.

Инпуты привязаны через v-model. Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе в первый инпут, второй инпут вычислялся автоматически и записывалось в объект newProduct? (и наоборот при вводе во второй, первый тоже вычислится и подставит значение)

Пробовал вычисляемым свойством, но похоже оно не работает вместе с v-model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `computed` свойства и `get/set` в них
Вот сделал вам пример: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ktfxsou3--bisy0VNBP

```html
<template>
  <div class="my-component">
    <input type="text" v-model="price_without_vat">
    <input type="text" v-model="price_with_vat">
    <pre>{{newProduct}}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    data() {
      return {
        newProduct: {
          price_without_vat: 'price_without_vat',
          price_with_vat: 'price_with_vat'
        } 
      }
    },
    computed: {
      price_without_vat: {
        get () {
          return this.newProduct.price_without_vat
        },
        set (value) {
          this.newProduct.price_without_vat = value
        }
      },
      price_with_vat: {
        get () {
          return this.newProduct.price_with_vat
        },
        set (value) {
          this.newProduct.price_with_vat = value
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: А как вызывать этот сеттер в input'e, если у меня уже есть привязка через v-model?

Comment: Так он сам вызываться должен ведь.

Comment: Можешь в ответ пример маленького кода написать? с 2-мя инпутами?